# Configuración de MaxReceivedMessageSize no funciona

Tags: c#, wcf

Estoy trabajando con un proyecto en el que se hacen múltiples llamadas a un WCF que está configurado así:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IWCF" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IWCF" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
          openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
          allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
              establishSecurityContext="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="URLWCF"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IWCF"
        contract="WCF.IWCF" name="BasicHttpBinding_IWCF" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
        ---------
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Pero al realizar algunas llamadas me sale este error:

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

Lo curioso es que ya tengo definido el `MaxReceivedMessageSize` en la configuración que he compartido con el valor:

```
maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
```

¿Qué se me escapa?

Comment: Creo que el problema está en el binding al cual hacés referencia. Estás seguro que en vez del Basic estás apuntando al wsHttpBinding? De lo contrario asegurate de que el basicHttpBinding -> MaxReceivedMessageSize sea el que tenga el máximo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con estos ajustes a tu webconfig:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IWCF" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880"
            maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IWCF" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
      openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
      allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
        enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
          establishSecurityContext="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="URLWCF"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IWCF"
    contract="WCF.IWCF" name="BasicHttpBinding_IWCF" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
        ---------
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Básicamente lo que ajusté fue lo del `<basicHttpBinding>`.

Espero te sirva